# What are these small marks?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: screenshot]

What are these little marks on the arms of the model?

They randomly appeared after I pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in **Object Mode** and I cant get rid of them, it also didn't let me undo so I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: This seems to be some kind of topology issue, non-manifold faces, disconnected vertices etc. Please upload blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look as marked with the red arrow;
[image]

Edges is seems to be pushed back, Try Alt + Click and bring it forward

Alternatively try, wireframe mode to view the all edges, by hitting Z key in edit mode or selecting Wireframe under viewport shading.